# Difference between doctrine:mapping:convert and doctrine:mapping:import

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to generate entity classes from a database for my symfony application.
So I followed the following three steps (From [How to generate Entities from an Existing Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html))

```
 1. php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force

 2. php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle yml

 3. php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

For knowing the working of these three commands, I just removed all files from **./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm**. I added one more field in one table. After that I followed command-2 and command-3.

I checked the modified table's entity for the new field. The new field was present in the entity.

Then why should we use the **doctrine:mapping:convert** command in order to generate entities from an existing database?

Comment: I feel that Symfony has not good community support.

Comment: I didn't get good explanation. For the sake of losing points, I am giving the points to the folks they tried to clarified me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have generated your entity classes, Doctrine is intelligent enough to get all the information it needs to import the mapping from the Entity classes, not needing the class metadata obtained in your first step. If you had deleted the metadata AND the entity classes then you would not be able to run step 2 without running step 1.

Comment: I Tried by removing "MyBundle/Entity/" and "MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/" and executing the step-2 and step-3. Generating classes successfully. I didn't use step-1.

Answer (score 6):

I don't quite understand what you guys are saying there, because for me the 3 commands are needed and different between themselves.

If you want to introspect a DB schema to generate the needed symfony ORM files and entities then you must use the 3 commands.

Here is what they do:
1)

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/< vendor>/< bundle_name>/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

This builds entity mapping files from the DB by introspection.For each table on the DB this will merely generate an < entity>.orm.yml in:

```
< proj_folder>/src/< vendor>/< bundle_name>/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm/< entity>.orm.yml
```

2)

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import < vendor>< bundle_name> annotation**
```

Generate entity classes for each table introspected from DB:

OUTPUT: `writing /var/www/html/< project_folder>/src/< vendor>/< bundle_name>/Entity/< entity>.php`

3)

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities < vendor>< nameBundle>**
```

This only generate getters and setters for all entity class properties.

Answer (score 4):

What I know, and as I explained it in [this post](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/06/some-tips-for-doctrine2-entities.html), **mapping:convert can't resolve namespaces for relations in your model**. That's why you then need to process mapping:import and get your final mapping files. After mapping:import has been processed, you can delete `YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm` directory.

Comment: That is true. mapping:convert doesn't resolve namespaces and mapping:import does. That is the only difference as far as my observation. But I tried the step-2 and step-3 without running the step-1, and it is generating the entities without any error. I think step-1 and step-2 are independent. Because in step-1, we are giving a path information but we don't mention the path in the step-2. Then how do the step-2 know where the files generated by the step-1 ?

Comment: Have you tried with a schema having foreign keys ? I think this is the case it does not work without step 1, relations are not fully qualified.

Comment: Did you delete metadata files before processing mapping:import ? Sorry if it's obvious.... :D

Comment: I followed the 3 steps, but some of the .php classes are not generated even though the equivalent orm.yml and orm.xml are generated, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your entites are all in the same bundle ? If no, are these bundles mapped by entity manager ?